# Why does this code throw an IOException?

Tags: java, ioexception

Why does this code throw an `IOException`?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File("File1.txt"));
             Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("File2.txt"))) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An IOException has been thrown.");
        } 
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

I am learning this from a book, but don't understand why it throws an exception. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In your exception `println`, output 'e' as well so that you can see what the error is.  It will tell you why it threw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the constructor `Scanner(File)` throws a `FileNotFoundException` which is a sub class of `IOException`. Check the javadoc for more [details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)).